# Check Xcode/iOS SDK version used to compile the app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Let's say I'm building a SDK and I want it to work on both Xcode 10 and Xcode 11.
What can I do to make some code like this to also compile in Xcode 10?

```
var style = UIStatusBarStyle.default
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
  style = UIStatusBarStyle.darkContent       
}
```

Since `.darkContent` is only available on iOS 13, I would have assumed that the `if #available(iOS 13.0, *)` should be enough. That works fine on Xcode 11, but on Xcode 10 I get this compile error:

> Type 'UIStatusBarStyle' has no member 'darkContent'

In Objective-C I've used this kind of macros

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 130000
// Use something that is only available on Xcode 11 and Xcode 10 doesn't understand
#endif
```

But that doesn't work in Swift

So, is there some similar way on Swift to detect that the code is running on Xcode 10 or compiled with SDK 12?

Comment: Not perfect but you could use `#if compiler(>=5.1) ... #endif`. 5.1 is the version of the compiler that comes with Xcode 11, so the code won't be compiled in Xcode 10.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to go with `UIStatusBarStyle.init(rawValue: 2)` because it makes my code simpler in this case, but if you put that as an answer I'll accept it as that was what I was asking for.

Comment: correction `UIStatusBarStyle.darkContent` is `UIStatusBarStyle.init(rawValue: 3)`, not 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not perfect but you could use

```
#if compiler(>=5.1)
  if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    style = UIStatusBarStyle.darkContent       
  }
#endif.
```

5.1 is the version of the compiler that comes with Xcode 11, so the code won't be compiled in Xcode 10. You'll still need the run-time `if #available` check in addition to the compile-time `#if` check.